# Remove single quote of string using `ast` but receive: ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x12f39fa30> - Python

Tags: python, string, character

```
a='[{"M":{"Options":{"L":[{"M":{"Label":{"S":"5PCS "},"Selected":{"BOOL":false},"OptionId":{"S":"3080a2b2-2fd1-11ed-a261-0242ac120002"},"Price":{"N":"0"}}},{"M":{"Label":{"S":"8PCS"},"Selected":{"BOOL":false},"OptionId":{"S":"27f2148c-2fd1-11ed-a261-0242ac120002"},"Price":{"N":"600"}}}]},"Type":{"S":"multiple"},"Description":{"S":"PCS "},"Required":{"BOOL":true},"Max":{"S":"1"},"Index":{"N":"0"},"Remove":{"BOOL":false},"Selected":{"N":"0"}}}]'
ast.literal_eval(a)
```

I am trying to remove the outside single quote and expect the output as:

```
[{"M":{"Options":{"L":[{"M":{"Label":{"S":"5PCS "},"Selected":{"BOOL":false},"OptionId":{"S":"3080a2b2-2fd1-11ed-a261-0242ac120002"},"Price":{"N":"0"}}},{"M":{"Label":{"S":"8PCS"},"Selected":{"BOOL":false},"OptionId":{"S":"27f2148c-2fd1-11ed-a261-0242ac120002"},"Price":{"N":"600"}}}]},"Type":{"S":"multiple"},"Description":{"S":"PCS "},"Required":{"BOOL":true},"Max":{"S":"1"},"Index":{"N":"0"},"Remove":{"BOOL":false},"Selected":{"N":"0"}}}]
```

But receive :

```
ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x12f39fa30>
```

I don't understand why I received this error since my input is `string`. Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: There are no single quotes to remove; they are part of the syntax for defining a `str` literal, not part of the resulting `str` value itself. `print(a)` would show you the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not a valid Python "literal". If you look carefully at the value of `a`, you'll see the value `false`, which is not the same as the Python Boolean literal `False`.

The value of `a` is, however, a valid JSON array (as `false` and `true` are the JSON Boolean values).

```
>>> json.loads(a)
[{'M': {'Options': {'L': [{'M': {'Label': {'S': '5PCS '}, 'Selected': {'BOOL': False}, 'OptionId': {'S': '3080a2b2-2fd1-11ed-a261-0242ac120002'}, 'Price': {'N': '0'}}}, {'M': {'Label': {'S': '8PCS'}, 'Selected': {'BOOL': False}, 'OptionId': {'S': '27f2148c-2fd1-11ed-a261-0242ac120002'}, 'Price': {'N': '600'}}}]}, 'Type': {'S': 'multiple'}, 'Description': {'S': 'PCS '}, 'Required': {'BOOL': True}, 'Max': {'S': '1'}, 'Index': {'N': '0'}, 'Remove': {'BOOL': False}, 'Selected': {'N': '0'}}}]
```